# Windows 10 installation cannot go to next phase

Tags: windows-10, installation, troubleshooting, windows-installation, bootable-media

I'm trying to install windows 10 on MSI gf63, but refuses to install with dialog box [dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUt97.jpg)
I have 2 storage device 1TB HDD and 512GB SSD both complete blank
[HDD & SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owLIT.jpg)
Also im confused while installing on SSD drive why does windows Installer also creates 100mb system partition on HDD [SYSTEM PARTITIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpVYU.jpg)

Comment: The 100 MB system partition is completely normal. Is your machine Windows 10 compliant? Can you update BIOS on the machine and try installing again.

Comment: Yes, actually windows 10 home came pre installed, and I've updated bios recently and on MSI website there is no new bios update for my system

Comment: Does the computer vendor offer a Recovery USB?  You may need that to load the requisite drivers.  It appears to be a driver stopping the install.

Comment: If Windows 10 home came preinstalled, how come the drives are now blank? Where did you get the installation media? If you're missing an important [driver](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GF63-Thin-9SX-GTX), you will need to slipstream it into the boot media.